# Given a dataframe with N elements, how can make m smaller dataframes such that the size of each m is some fraction of N?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset (call it Data) with ~25000 instances that I want to split into a train set, development set, and test set. I want it to be such that,

```
train set = 0.7*Data
development set = 0.1*Data
test set = 0.2*Data
```

When making the split, I want the instances to be randomly sampled and NOT REPEATED between the 3 sets. This is why I can't use something like,

```
train_set = Data.sample(frac=0.7)
dev_set = Data.sample(frac=0.1)
train_set = Data.sample(frac=0.2)
```

where instances from Data may be repeated in the sets. Is there a build in function that I am missing or could you help me write a function for doing this?

I will use an array to demonstrate an example of what I am looking for.

```
A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
splits = [0.7, 0.1, 0.2]

def splitFunction(data, array_of_splits):
    // I need your help here

splits = splitFunction(A, splits)
#output
[[1, 3, 8, 9, 6, 7, 2], [4], [5, 0]]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import shuffle

def splitFunction(data, array_of_splits):
    data_copy = data[:]    # copy data if don't want to change original array
    shuffle(data_copy)    # randomizes data
    splits = []
    startIndex = 0
    for val in array_of_splits:
        split = data_copy[startIndex:startIndex + val*len(data)]
        startIndex = startIndex + val*len(data)
        splits.append(split)
    return splits
```

Comment: Thanks! This is similar to a solution that I tried to implement after posting this question. Had to make a couple changes to your code to make it play nice with a data frame, but it works perfectly!!